# react hooks not setting the select value after fetching options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, use-effect

1. I am fetching list of testsuites using api call on component mount. Api returns list in chronological order.
2. Setting them as options for a select dropdown(Material-UI).
3. Then set the selected option to latest testSuite and using its Id get the corresponding testSuite data.
4. Data is retrieved successfully and pie chart is getting displayed.
5. Api calls are working fine and React dev tools shows the selectedTestSuite value to be set correctly.But DOM doesn't show the selection in the select dropdown.

Can someone please advise what is the mistake I am doing in this code? Thanks in advance.

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';
import '../../Dashboard.css';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardContent,
  Divider,
  TextField,
} from '@material-ui/core';

import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  circularloader: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },
  actions: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  inputField: {
    width: '150px',
  },
}));
const TestSuiteVsScanCount = (props) => {
  const { className, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [doughData, setDoughData] = useState([]);
  const [dataLoadedFlag, setDataLoadedFlag] = useState(false);
  const [testSuites, setTestSuites] = useState([]);
  const [selectedTestSuite, setSelectedTestSuite] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    function getTestSuites() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/testsuite/12').then((resp) => {
        setTestSuites(resp.data.reverse());
      });
    }
    getTestSuites();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (testSuites.length > 0) {
      setSelectedTestSuite(() => {
        return {
          type: testSuites[0].TestSuiteName,
          id: testSuites[0].TestSuiteId,
        };
      });
    }
  }, [testSuites]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function getTestSuiteData() {
      let doughData = [];
      if (selectedTestSuite.id) {
        axios
          .get(
            'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/summary/piechart/12?days=30&testsuiteid=' +
              selectedTestSuite.id,
          )
          .then((resp) => {
            resp.data.forEach((test) => {
              doughData = [test.TestCount, test.ScanCount];
            });
            setDoughData({
              labels: ['Test Count', 'Scan Count'],
              datasets: [
                {
                  data: doughData,
                  backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB'],
                  hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB'],
                },
              ],
            });
            setDataLoadedFlag(true);
          });
      }
    }
    getTestSuiteData();
  }, [selectedTestSuite]);

  const ChangeType = (id) => {
    testSuites.forEach((suite) => {
      if (suite.TestSuiteId === id) {
        setSelectedTestSuite({
          type: suite.TestSuiteName,
          id: suite.TestSuiteId,
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Card {...rest} className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
      <CardHeader
        action={
          <TextField
            select
            label="Select Test Suite"
            placeholder="Select Tests"
            value={selectedTestSuite.id}
            className={classes.inputField}
            name="tests"
            onChange={(event) => ChangeType(event.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          >
            {testSuites.map((testSuite) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={testSuite.TestSuiteId}
                value={testSuite.TestSuiteId}
              >
                {testSuite.TestSuiteName}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        }
        title="Test Suite vs Scan Count"
      />
      <Divider />
      <CardContent>
        <div>
          {dataLoadedFlag ? (
            <Doughnut data={doughData} />
          ) : (
            <CircularProgress
              thickness="1.0"
              size={100}
              className={classes.circularloader}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </CardContent>
      <Divider />
    </Card>
  );
};

TestSuiteVsScanCount.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

export default TestSuiteVsScanCount;
```

Comment: So the `selectedTestSuite.id` does not appears in `TextField` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with the help of my colleague by setting the initial state of `selectedTestSuite` to `{type:'', id:0}` instead of `{}`.

Changed this

```
const [selectedTestSuite, setSelectedTestSuite] = useState({});
```

To this

```
const [selectedTestSuite, setSelectedTestSuite] = useState({type:'', id:0});
```

But I am not sure why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the main problem is when you pass a `value` to `TextField` component with `undefined`, the `TextField` component will assume that is an uncontrolled component.

When you set you initial state for `selectedTestSuite` to be `{}` the `value` for `selectedTestSuite.id` will be undefined. You can find `value` API reference in https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/